# Adding ggvis plot in RMarkdown document makes knitr::kable output render incorrectly

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown, ggvis

Reproducible example below. I lose formatting on the table whenever I include a `ggvis` figure.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(knitr)
```

The following table looks fine...

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cars %>% kable(format = 'markdown')
```

As long as I don't include this plot below

```{r, echo=FALSE}
pressure %>%
  ggvis(x = ~temperature, y = ~pressure) %>%
  layer_bars()
```
````

Comment: for what it's worth, I was able to "fix" this by changing the `kable` call to be `kable(format = "html", table.attr = 'class=\"table table=striped table-hover \"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to a bug that has been fixed in the development version of ggvis. If you install the latest with `devtools::install_github('rstudio/ggvis')`, it should work.